# How to transform apex static resource url (image) code to html?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, salesforce, apex

I have the data url of my image in the static resource library, but I want to change it in html form so that I can customize it's class from css. I don't want to  edit my css.

Here is my apex static resource url code:

```
<apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.mikee}" width="140" height="140"/>
```

Also, i just copied this code from a certain site, so I'm really not sure how the 'id' works. I mean it says that it's a generated id.

Anyway, I want it to be like this:

```
 <img class="img img-circle img-responsive" id="mikee" data-src="[mikee]/mikee.jpg"/>
```

I'm using bootstrap to make a circular cut on my image.. However, it's not working, what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [apex:image](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_compref_image.htm) documentation.

To set the class in the resulting HTML you need to set the `styleClass` attribute. E.g.

```
<apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.mikee}" width="140" height="140" styleClass="img img-circle img-responsive"/>
```

If you want to set the HTML data-src attribute you can use the [Salesforce pass-through attributes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm). E.g.

```
<apex:image id="theImage" html-data-src="[mikee]/mikee.jpg" width="140" height="140" styleClass="img img-circle img-responsive"/>
```

Note that the `{!$Resource.mikee}` Visualforce notation is going to give you a URI to the Resource image. It isn't intended to read the content of the resource as a string path. You might be better off with a custom setting and then using `{!Setup.MyCustomSetting__c.Url__c}`

Finally, there is a dedicated [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) site that is a great place for asking Salesforce specific questions.